# Selecting mysql row containing user id inside a field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am working on some type of private conversations site and I am storing conversations on a table (Messages are stored on another table)

That's the format:

- Id: Auto incrementing
- Title: Varchar, represents the name of the conversation
- Members: Saves the ids of the members with access to the conversation

My problem is that the way that I'm storing members is literally horrible.     I'm using `user1Id;user2Id;user3Id`.

The problem appears when trying to get all conversations of a specific player.

My question is: Is there any better way of storing the ids? (On one field if possible) and also being able to select all conversations of a specific id?

Comment: Then change the way that you're storing members, otherwise you're just going to continue running into problems.... normalize your database tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "proper", normalized, database way would be to have another table, `member_conversation_map` with two columns - the member ID and the conversation ID,  and query it with, e.g., an `in` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   conversations
WHERE  id IN (SELECT conversation_id
              FROM   member_conversation_map
              WHERE  member_id = 123)
```

If that's not an option, and you positively have to have the member IDs in a single cell in the database, at least use commas instead of semicolons as your delimiter. This will allow you to use MySQL's [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT *
FROM   conversations
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('123', members) > 0
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the performance of `FIND_IN_SET` is usually abysmal on tables of non-trivial size. The first query should run in near zero time if things are properly indexed, but the second could ruin your server by having to scan each row. Using a `JOIN` might simplify the first query, too.

Comment: @Strawberry It's pretty quick on a per-row basis, but if you have a hundred million conversations good luck scanning that table.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make a member to conversation table? In there you can store members and conversations like this

```
member_id | conversation_id
        1 |               1
        2 |               1
        3 |               1
        1 |               2
        2 |               2
```

Meaning member 1, 2 and 3 are part of conversation 1 and member 1 and 2 are of conversation 2

Thats how i do stuff like this and its working good this way.

If you still want to store them in one field, your way would be the best, since you can split them by their seperator and have all ids in an array that way. But as you pointed out, getting conversations by an user id is getting messy pretty quick using this method.

Answer (score 0):

One way to store is using a json array: Define member_ids to VARCHAR and store priviliges ids like:

```
["11","1","2","3"]
```

Using json_decode you can get the members when required.

Comment: The only way to select with that will be using LIKE with "11" and that's not what I'd like to do

Comment: Why Like? Check if the current id is in the privileged array..You have to search all conversation ids anyway...Tell me how u wanna do it?

Comment: Do try and use full English words and not "txt" abbreviations. Some people are dependent on translation tools or are not familiar with all these words.

Comment: In Postgres these types of JSON columns can be indexed by the elements they contain and they perform quite well, but sadly MySQL's support is extremely limited in comparison. Using JSON here isn't necessarily the best call.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 also adds support for searching fields containing JSON. But I don't think they're indexed, so it will be slow.